# Перенос данных с одной страницы сайта на другой

Tags: html, css, веб-программирование

Есть форма на одной странице, и когда нажимаешь на кнопку осуществляется переход в другую страницу со своей формой. Как можно сделать так, чтобы данные одного поля с первой формы записались на вторую без базы данных?

Answer (score 0):

Если кнопка, по нажатии которой осуществляется переход, - `<input type='submit' />`, то вы можете в `<form>` на первой странице прописать `method='get'`, а на второй странице написать небольшой скрипт, из которого удобным способом будете доставлять в инпуты значения параметров той формы, из которой произошел редирект.
Например, в первой форме была форма из одного поля `<input name='name' />` (ну и кнопкой `<input type='submit' name='button' value='button' />`). По сабмиту произошел переход по вашему адресу с search-припиской `https://redirect.link.com?name=<some entered data>&button=button`. На этой странице скрипт:

```
let params = new URL(location.href).searchParams;
let firstInput = params.get('name');        //<some entered data>
```

Данные из firstInput уже записываете в инпут, как вам удобно

Comment: просто добавить этот скрипт? У меня не работает, firstInput выдает null

Comment: Добавьте этот код в функцию, которая будет запускаться по событию load элемента body. Может быть, в этом проблема (если у вас все правильно в форме на первой странице и вы пытаетесь получать в firstInput параметр, который действительно есть в ссылке)